# Requests body empty

Tags: python, http, python-requests

Why does the following print None?

```
import requests
r = requests.request('http://cnn.com', data={"foo":"bar"})
print r.request.body
# None
```

If you change cnn.com to www.cnn.com, it prints the proper body. I noticed a redirect (there is a 301 in r.history). What's going on?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `requests.request('get',...)` or `requests.get()`, `requests.post()`?

Comment: Please **copy-paste** (do not type) an **exact** program that demonstrates the error. See http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 2):

Your code as it stands doesn't actually work—it'll raise a `TypeError` right off the bat. But I think I can guess at what you're trying to do.

If you change that `request` to a `post`, it will indeed successfully return `None`.

Why? Because you're asking for the body of the redirect, not the body of the original request. For that, you want `r.history[0].request.body`.

Read [Redirection and History](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) for more info. Note that auto-redirecting isn't actually documented to work for POST requests, even though it often does anyway. Also note that in earlier versions of `requests`, `history` entries didn't have complete `Request` objects. (You'll have to look at the [version history](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/HISTORY.rst) if you need to know when that changed. But it seems to be there in 1.2.0, and not in 0.14.2—and a lot of things that were added or changes in 1.0.0 aren't really documented, because it was a major rewrite.)

---

As a side note… why do you need this? If you really need to know what body you sent, why not do the two-step process of creating a request and sending it, so you can see the body beforehand? (Or, for that matter, just encode the data explicitly?)